# Python : Default Dictionary Initialization

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have created a default dictionary as below :

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(lambda : "Key not    found")
dd = {'a':1,'b':2}
print(dd) 
print(dd['a']) # Prints 1
print(dd['c'])  # Throws KeyError
```

But, the below code snippet works :

```
from collections import defaultdict
(lambda : "Key not    found")
dd['a']=1
dd['b']=2
print(dd) 
print(dd['a']) # Prints 1
print(dd['c'])  # Prints "Key not found"
```

Could anyone please explain me why the first code snippet throws error whereas the second one runs fine as expected..

Answer (score 2):

You have overwritten `dd = defaultdict(lambda : "Key not    found")` with `dd = {'a':1,'b':2}` so that `defaultdict()` has became a `dict()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to delete the line 3 in the first snippet.
That has overwritten your dd whose type is defaultdict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below two lines of your code snippet -

```
dd = defaultdict(lambda : "Key not    found")
dd = {'a':1,'b':2}
```

In the first line, you are creating a **defaultdict** object and **dd** is pointing to this object -
[image: dict_object]

In the second line, you are creating a dictionary and now, saving its reference to **dd** -
[image]
 So, now as you can see in the picture above that **dd** is pointing to a new dictionary created in second line. And since, this new dictionary which **dd** is referring to is not having a key named 'c', you are getting a **Key not found** error.